# Converting ISO-8859-1 XML to UTF-8

Tags: javascript, xml, meteor, get

I'm receiving XML data from an API. The data is converted to JSON on my server and saved in my Mongo Database.

The problem is, the XML I receive is encoded in **ISO-8859-1** and uses scandinavian letters **å, ä and ö**. The encoding is not specified in the response headers.

I am able to view the XML in my browser, the special letters show up just fine, but in my GET request response, the special letters show up as a question mark in a black box (�) in the console and in MongoDB.

In my GET request, I send the `"Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8"` headers but the response is still sent in ISO-8859-1.

What are my options here? Can I somehow convert � to the right characters?

### Additional information

Updated again:

```
response = HTTP.call('GET', 'http://removed.url/rss.xml', {
    headers: {
        "Accept-Charset": "utf-8"
    }
});
data = Buffer.from(response.content, 'binary').toString('binary');

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sending `Content-Type` in `GET` response doesn't make sense. This header indicates media type of the resource and it is server who sends this header in response to your `GET` request. Also, it could be sent in `PUT` or `POST` requests in order to indicate media type of sent content.

You should probably use [`Accept-Charset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Charset) header, it tells server which charset(s) the client is able to understand:

```
Accept-Charset: utf-8
```

Also, that could be a reason of `XML` sent with `ISO-8859-1` charset:

> In early versions of HTTP/1.1, a default charset (ISO-8859-1) was defined. This is no more the case and now each content type may have its own default.

Anyway, if this api service you're using doesn't support `Accept-Charset` you can convert encodings yourself, before storing it into the DB.

**Added:**

Converting this response content to `utf8` is tricky thing: Meteor's `HTTP.call` returns it already as `utf8` string, so in `response.content` you already have `ISO-8859-1` string treated as `utf8` string.

You have to use `Buffer` to do convert it back:

```
data = Buffer.from(response.content, 'binary').toString('binary');
```

I've tested it myself with this url and it works as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, it turns out the service always sends the data in ISO-8859-1. I've tried using Iconv to convert to UTF-8, like so: `data = new iconv.Iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'utf-8').convert(response.content).toString();`, but it changes the characters to **ï¿½**.

Comment: I've added additional information in my original post above.

Comment: Hmm, the characters are now changed to `ý` for me. Do I still have to use iconv to convert anything? I've updated my question, to show what I have now.